# Retrieve Last Updated Record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i retrieve last updated EmpID form sql database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SCOPE_IDENTITY() after your insert or update statement.

```
UPDATE Foo SET column1 = 'newValue'
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [LastUpdatedID]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx